# R grouped barplot from one row of a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame:

```
                X2    X13    X18     X3   X15    X19
comp162192_c0 194.63 118.80 149.67  71.02 59.49  75.03
comp166160_c1 535.49 595.86 535.97 171.93 86.01 268.39
comp149395_c1  45.98  99.92  74.21  26.46 14.72  27.69
```

I would like to produce a barplot from one row of this data such that the values from X2, X13 and X18 are grouped and the values from X3, X15, X19 are grouped. ie. a set of 3 vertical bars with values 194.63 118.80 149.67,a gap, then a set of 3 vertical bars with values 71.02 59.49  75.03

Can't see a simple way to do this. I am missing something I know but I can't make head nor tail of the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the help file for the `barplot()` function, you will see this explanation for the argument `height`,

> ... either a vector or matrix of values describing the bars which make
>   up the plot. ... If height is a matrix and beside is TRUE, then the
>   values in each column are juxtaposed rather than stacked.

So, you need to rearrange your data such that the groups of numbers you want to plot are in a single columns in a matrix.  You can do this with the `cbind()` function to each of the three values you want to plot.

```
df <- structure(list(X2 = c(194.63, 535.49, 45.98), X13 = c(118.8, 
    595.86, 99.92), X18 = c(149.67, 535.97, 74.21), X3 = c(71.02, 
    171.93, 26.46), X15 = c(59.49, 86.01, 14.72), X19 = c(75.03, 
    268.39, 27.69)), .Names = c("X2", "X13", "X18", "X3", "X15", 
    "X19"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("comp162192_c0", 
    "comp166160_c1", "comp149395_c1"))

barplot(cbind(unlist(df[1, 1:3]), unlist(df[1, 4:6])), beside=TRUE)
```

*(Note that I used the `dput()` function to share your data in a way that other folks can easily access it in R.)*

Comment: Thanks, I read the help file, understanding it (for me) requires an example, which I now have, thanks a lot!